# What does the 't()' tag mean in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, escaping

I came across some opensource code in views, with a `t()` tag similar to the HTML escape sequence `h()`.

```
<%= f.label :password, t(:password, :scope => "activerecord.attributes.user") -%>
```

What does `t()` mean?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

t(keys, options = {})

Alias for translate

translate(keys, options = {})

Delegates to `I18n#translate` but also performs two additional functions. First, it‘ll catch `MissingTranslationData` exceptions and turn them into inline spans that contains the missing key, such that you can see in a view what is missing where.

Second, it‘ll scope the key by the current partial if the key starts with a period. So if you call `translate(".foo")` from the people/index.html.erb template, you‘ll actually be calling `I18n.translate("people.index.foo")`. This makes it less repetitive to translate many keys within the same partials and gives you a simple framework for scoping them consistently. If you don‘t prepend the key with a period, nothing is converted.
This method is also aliased as t

Comment: docs link for reference: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Answer (score 1):

Do the translation of key in `.yml` files in `config/locales`

```
t(:password)
```

key is "password"